# Create a timer with Ratchet php

Tags: php, sockets, timer, websocket

I am strugling with an idea I have with my socket server. It's based on ratchet php.

What I want to achieve is after a certain event I would like to set a timer. When the timer is finished, to notify every connection. When I use the `sleep` function, my socket server sleeps and can't accept anything for that time.

Can you guys please give me an idea of how to do it, or is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never block the work of event-loop server...

To create a timer - you need to contact LoopInterface (Reactphp library).

Usually it is in the server classes (eg IOServer)

That's how you can create a timer:

```
$this->loop->addPeriodicTimer($timeout, function($timer) {

});
```